# How to properly transpile with Parcel-bundler?

Tags: typescript, sass, parceljs

I'm trying to transpile both `.ts (TYPESCRIPT)` and `.scss (SASS)` files ..

**The problem that is occurring are two:**

**1)** It does not generate my file in my dist directory, it creates a dist directory inside the build folder.

**2)** It is creating .js and .map files, plus it is not mimicking the .css and .ts files. (Why does it create the other files and does it not mimic?)

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn sass",
    "sass": "parcel watch --no-cache ./scss/*.scss ../../dist/css/index.css",
    "ts": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.11.0",
    "sass": "^1.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Parcel you don't need to have separate scripts in package.json. You just need to add references or imports to the files you want to compile. E.g.:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Link to your Sass file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.scss" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Link to your TypeScript file -->
    <script src="./index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then you simply run `parcel index.html` from your terminal, or via a script in your package.json:

```
"start": "parcel index.html",
```

Or if you're compiling TS directly then you can simply run `parcel` on a TS file directly, e.g. for this file:

**index.ts**

```
import "style.scss"; // Sass file import

console.log("Hello World!");
```

you can run `parcel index.ts` and Parcel will compile both the TS and the referenced Sass file.

Comment: I understand, but what if I do this is the same thing as what I was doing .. it is generating a dist folder within build .. Being that this is not what I want .. I already have the dist folder out of the build I just want to insert the transpiled file into it .. How to do this?